# Unable to find index for $geoNear Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, moloquent

I am using the [Moloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) model with Laravel 5.6. here is my collection record given below:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afe619dbe0b8d0e5876b16b"),
    "name" : "Central Park",
    "categories" : [ 
        "4d4b7105d754a06376d81259", 
        "4bf58dd8d48988d116941735", 
        "4bf58dd8d48988d119941735", 
        "4d4b7105d754a06376d81259", 
        "4bf58dd8d48988d116941735", 
        "4bf58dd8d48988d119941735", 
        "4d4b7105d754a06374d81259", 
        "4bf58dd8d48988d16d941735"
    ],
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            88.4166612820784, 
            22.5835157504658
        ]
    }
}
```

I am running this query from the Laravel controller.

```
$users = MongoTest::where('loc', 'near', [
                    '$geometry' => [
                        'type' => 'Point',
                        'coordinates' => [
                            $longitude,
                            $latitude,
                        ],
                    ],
                    '$maxDistance' => 10,
                ])->get();

print_r($users);
```

I am getting this error:-

```
error processing query: ns=tkit.testTree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=10 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: By creating a geospatial index of course. The error is telling you that you do not have an index in place and there needs to be one on the `"loc"` field.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do that, I mean the structure? I am new to MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index from the mongo shell. A [`2sphere` index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) is expected by the query using the [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) or [`$nearSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) operator or [`geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) command, or even the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation pipeline stage.

The [`createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) method will do this for you, so just name your collection within the correct database:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ "loc": "2dsphere" })
```

Note that any API actually using the [`geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) command really needs to update to one of the other mentioned query operators as this command is "deprecated" from MongoDB 4.0 onwards and will be removed.

Operations looking for "nearest" should use [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) or [`$nearSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/), and those which want to return the "distance" should use the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipelie stage instead.